Django ORM - Prevent null field being included in the insert statement
I have a Django model resembling the following:
class SomeClass(CoreModel):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    auto_increment_id = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, db_index=True)

I want to increment the auto_increment_id field directly in the database using DEFAULT value. In fact I modified my table in the test db and when I manually insert a row, this works as expected.
When I insert a new record through Django though, this field remains as Null, because the SQL that Django produces includes this field as well with a NULL value.
I've tried setting this field to a BigAutoField but it seems this field should be used as a primary key and since I have another primary key, this is not an option. Needless to say, this is a production code and I cannot change my primary key.
Any methods to prevent this behaviour?

set primary_key=True

@django.seolpyo.com I've already stated that I cannot do that if you read through the question.

Clarify your question, or use AutoField
